# How to add a background image + backgroung color with opacity?

Tags: html, css

How to add a `background-image + background-color` with opacity for `body` tag?

Answer (score 0):

**try this code** include the div tags in your body!

```css
.background {
    background:url('http://placehold.it/100x100');
    position: relative;
    height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.layer {
    background-color: rgba(75, 86, 160, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="background">
    <div class="layer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-blend-mode` on the `<div>` that has the `background-image`.

**EDIT:** You might want to create a `<div>` element that acts as the main container for your site instead of adding the background image onto `<body>`.

```css
.card__image {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    
    /* Change the opacity of Dodger Blue background by
       selecting a value between 0-1 for the fourth argument. */
    background: rgba(34, 167, 240, 0.75);
    background-image: url('https://unsplash.it/300');
    background-blend-mode: multiply;
}
```

```html
<div class="card__image"></div>
```